# PHP, файл в массив и цикл с обработкой строк

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

есть файл 1.txt со словами:

- text12
- text123
- text1234

  ..и т.д.(1 слово в каждой строке)

  **задумка:** считать данный файл в массив, вывести общее количество строк в файле, дальше разбор каждого слова: а именно: вывод слова - количество букв в данном слове, и необходимо показать первую и последнюю букву данного слова. без цикла все показывается хорошо, пробую с циклом показывает все неверно, помогите разобраться в чем дело, где моя ошибка

  ```
  $fp = file("1.txt");
  echo 'Количество строк в файле: '.count($fp);
  echo "<hr>";
  for ($i = 0; $i <= count($fp); $i++) {
  $fp = file("1.txt");
  $str = trim($fp[i]);
  $word = $fp[$i];
  echo "<hr>".$word."</br>";
  echo "Букв:&nbsp; ".iconv_strlen($word)."</br>"; //количество букв в слове
  echo "Первая:&nbsp; <b>(".$word{0}.")</b>"; //первая буква
  echo "&nbsp;Последняя:&nbsp; <b>(".substr($word, strlen($word)-1, 1).")</b></br>"; //последняя буква
  }
  ```

  вот что показывает

  > Количество строк в файле: 3
  >   text12
  >   Букв: 8
  >   Первая: (t) Последняя:  ( )
  >   text123
  >   Букв:  9
  >   Первая: (t) Последняя: ( )
  >   text1234
  >   Букв:  8
  >   Первая:  (t) Последняя:  (4)

> Букв:  0
>   Первая:  () Последняя:  ()
>   так же показывает 4 строку которой нету

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgets.php

Comment: проверяй строку на пустоту, потому что это нормальный кейс

Comment: используй substr, а еще лучше mb_substr и mb_strlen для utf-8 кодировки

Comment: count($fp) - тут не понятно. fp это не массив.

Comment: Четвертая строка - это перенос строки от третьей, спасает `trim` и проверка на пустоту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 строка дублирует первую, да еще и в цикле.

Для пробега по массиву есть `foreach`.

в 6й строке используете переменную `$str` и к значению из массива применяете `trim()`, но в 7й строке в переменную $word вы добавляете снова значение из массива не обработанное `trim()`.

в 10й можно использовать `substr($word, 0, 1)`.

в 11й можно использовать `substr($word, -1, 1)`.